# What libraries are available to help create 2D Java games for phones?

Tags: java, graphics, java-me, vector-graphics, pixel-fonts

I want to begin developing 2D Java games for phones (on J2ME) therefore I'd like to know if any libraries or "engines" exist to help out in the various graphical tasks:

- Drawing text with pixel fonts?
- Drawing bitmaps for sprites with multiple frames like animated GIFs?
- Drawing graphics with code, lines, beziers, flood-filling and [gradient fills](http://www.google.com/search?q=gradient+)?
- Ordering / layering of sprites?

Or maybe a great book exists, that gives you enough code samples to get off the ground quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use it myself, but heard some good reference on [here](http://j2megl.sourceforge.net/).

And [here](http://j2me.ngphone.com/opensource/gameplat.htm) is even a list of libraries, you might need.

Answer (score 4):

[MIDP (JSR-118)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118) includes the basics (most of the things you listed above) mainly in the [`javax.microedition.lcdui`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html) and [`javax.microedition.lcdui.game`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/package-summary.html) namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

There was a book released quite a few years ago called [Developing Games in Java](http://www.brackeen.com/javagamebook/) by David Brackeen.

That covers the basics of 2d and 3d development in pure Java as well as how to handle time jumps and update the physical properties of your game characters. It is a good introduction to the topic.