# j2me 2d graphics engine

Tags: graphics, frameworks, java-me, 2d

For J2ME I found a number of GUI frameworks like LWUIT, J2ME Polish, Twuik etc however,

I am looking out for a 2d Graphics Engine for the Java ME platform preferably lightweight < 50K, I came across [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/2d/index.html) this supports reasonable features for a mobile device.

On similar lines do we have an open source or free 2d graphics engine, library or framework available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this? [[What libraries are available to help create 2D Java games for phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284093/what-libraries-are-available-to-help-create-2d-java-games-for-phones/1284139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284093/what-libraries-are-available-to-help-create-2d-java-games-for-phones/1284139)

Comment: These are mostly tile based animations however I am looking for animations with lines, shapes, curves. Thanks.